# unable to get all row data from Jtable using for loop.. Giving me last row

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, iteration

Am trying to get row data from my Jtable using for loop but it is giving the last row. Below a sample of my code:

```
String item = null; String qty = null; String price = null;
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    String f1 =item.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
    String f2 =item.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();  
    String f3 =item.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(); 
    item = f1; qty = f2; price =f3;
}
Formatter fd = new Formatter();
System.out.println(fd.format("%-20s %5s %10s", item ,qty ,price ));
```

Comment: What result do you wish to get? From the code you posted, it is obvious that only the last table row will be printed by the call to method `println()`. Did you try debugging the code you posted?

Comment: I want to get all row data outside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the last two lines of your sample code so they are inside your loop: before the `}` that ends the loop.

Comment: Noted, but am trying to access the string outside the for loop

Comment: Perhaps provide more details about what you need to do. As O. Jones said, move the println inside the loop. As written, your loop is iterating through every element and putting it in the variables (item, qty and price), but not doing anything with them.
On the first iteration you get the first entry in item, qty and price. On the second, you get the second item (overwriting the first) and so on. Finally, **only** after every item has been captured and overrwritten into those 3 variables, only then do you print the variables and thus get just the last ones printed.

Comment: If, when the loop ends, you want a string with all entries in it, it’s time for you to read about the `StringBuilder` class and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You reassign new values to the variables `item`, `qty` and `price` with each loop. Hence only the last one is printed out. If you wish to print the values of each row, include the printing to console code **inside** the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    String f1 = item.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
    String f2 = item.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();  
    String f3 = item.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(); 
    System.out.println(String.format("%-20s %5s %10s", f1 , f2, f3));
}
```

Moreover, the method [`String.format(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) might be more interesting for you.

Comment: Or use `System.out.printf()`.